# Are there localized resource strings available for the JCL (JEDI Code Library)?

Tags: delphi, localization, translation, jedi-code-library

Is there a translation/localization sub-project for the [JEDI Code Library](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/)?

I'm especially looking for German, French and Italian versions of `JclResources.pas` and `JclVclResources.pas` (and might be able to contribute to a German translation myself). Is anything like that already in the works or did I even just fail to find it in the original sources?

So far Google has turned up nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have been able to determine there are no translated resource strings available to date.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know more than what I understand from their [Contributing page](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/Contributing.htm); it is done through the **jvcl.po** file that you can get from the repository and that should be installed under **\locale** :

*[...]*
*Localizing
If you speak another language than english, you can contribute by translating the texts in JVCL into other language(s) you know.*

*Translating JVCL is a matter of creating a copy of the jvcl.po file in the \locale folder of the JVCL installation and translate it using poEdit (http://poedit.sourceforge.net). Once you are done, you can upload the translated po file to either our bug tracker or to the jedi.binaries newsgroup and a JVCL developer will take care of adding it to CVS.*

Comment: that's the JVCL, i.e. the JEDI *Visual Component* Library, not the JCL